# Dirichlet generating function of Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, riemann-zeta

I am trying to figure out a question I have come across using Riemann Zeta function and Dirichlet generating functions. The function I am given is $$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)^2 = g(n),$$

we have,$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s}.$$
I understand this step, however its the next step where they simplify into Riemann zeta functions where
$$\zeta(s) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s}= \zeta(s) \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)},$$
Once again I know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} $ but still I am confused please may someone explain this for me.

Comment: $n \mapsto \mu(n)^2$ is the characteristic function of the squarefree integers. Based on that description, can you write down the Euler product for its Dirichlet generating function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with multiplicative functions, it is often easier to see what's going on if one looks at the Euler product. The function $n \mapsto \mu(n)^2$ is multiplicative (pointwise products of multiplicative functions are again multiplicative, and $\mu$ is multiplicative), so let's look at the Euler product:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s}
&= \prod_p \Biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(p^k)^2}{p^{ks}}\Biggr) \\
&= \prod_p \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{p^s}\biggr)
\end{align}

since $\mu(p^k)^2 = 1$ if $k \leqslant 1$ and $\mu(p^k)^2 = 0$ if $k \geqslant 2$.

Now we write the factors in the Euler product as

$$1 + \frac{1}{p^s} = \frac{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{p^s}\bigr)\bigl(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\bigr)}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}}$$

and see

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s} = \prod_p \frac{1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}}{1 - \frac{1}{p^s}} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}\,.$$